# How to add HSQLDB library to SpringMVC in Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, hsqldb

I would like to ask how to add HSQLDB library `hsqldb.jar` in Maven? I have project in Eclipse created as Spring Template Project from SpringSource Tool Suite. It uses Maven as far as I know. I would like my project to use and work with HSQL database. And at this moment I want my Tomcat server to use HSQLDB library file. So If I added this library file in Maven, my project would work properly with HQL database. This is my assumption.
I have found this example http://slu.livejournal.com/5965.html but adding the jar file to the class path isn't very good programmig practice, is it?
I'm newbie in Maven and also in Spring Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remember about `runtime` scope in such artifacts (most people forget about it), since you use some generic API/SPI (ORM or JDBC probably) for database access and HSQLDB is only some kind of vendor for run-time implementation of such API/SPI.